# To convert byte array to mp3 file

Tags: android, audio, android-audiorecord

I have written an application in android to record voice from mic and store it in byte array using

```
audioRecord.read(bigBuff, currSize, minBuffSize);
```

bigBuff is an byte array now i want to convert this byte array into .mp3 file or .wav file I am doing this as

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/aaa.wav");

f.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
fos.write(bigBuff);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

aaa.wav file is getting created successfully but when I am trying to play it from outside the app like any other .wav or .mp3 file its showing error "sorry Player does not support this type of audio file"

please help.

Comment: What is audioRecord.read?

Comment: audioRecord is an object of AudioRecord class and read is its method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't input data header.
add this mothod and after copy data.

```
        private void WriteWaveFileHeader(
                    FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
                    long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels,
                    long byteRate) throws IOException {

            byte[] header = new byte[44];

            header[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
            header[1] = 'I';
            header[2] = 'F';
            header[3] = 'F';
            header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
            header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
            header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
            header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
            header[8] = 'W';
            header[9] = 'A';
            header[10] = 'V';
            header[11] = 'E';
            header[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
            header[13] = 'm';
            header[14] = 't';
            header[15] = ' ';
            header[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
            header[17] = 0;
            header[18] = 0;
            header[19] = 0;
            header[20] = 1;  // format = 1
            header[21] = 0;
            header[22] = (byte) channels;
            header[23] = 0;
            header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
            header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
            header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
            header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
            header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
            header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
            header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
            header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
            header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8);  // block align
            header[33] = 0;
            header[34] = RECORDER_BPP;  // bits per sample
            header[35] = 0;
            header[36] = 'd';
            header[37] = 'a';
            header[38] = 't';
            header[39] = 'a';
            header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
            header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
            header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
            header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

            out.write(header, 0, 44);
    }
```

Comment: @VarunKarhadkar what you want your comment?

Comment: little more help needed what should I pass to method in place of totalAudioLen and byteRate.. I ma passing fileoutputstream=fos   totalDataLen=bigBuff.length(), int channels = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO  longSampleRate = 44100

Comment: Oh, sorry. first, you save .raw file in your data. After then, try this. FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream( .raw file ).
totalAudioLen is in.getChannel().size()

Comment: byteRate is ( Bit per sample value *  44100( sample rate ) * 1 ( if you chouse mono ) / 8 )

Comment: Amadas I am sorry but I am not getting what your are saying... should I first save my bigBuff data in .raw file then read it using FileinputStream then again save this file including header at front as .wav file.

Comment: Yes. and TotalDataLen is just totalAudioLen + 36.

Comment: OK.. thank you I will try this right away and let you know the result.

Comment: Okay. I use this code just use and maker is another. I'm sorry help any more.

Answer (score 1):

To configure header refer to following links

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html

Above header do not work for me but after making minor changes in configuration its working perfectly.